# Android MediaCodec decoding to Surface in Async mode

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-mediacodec, surface

The CTS example code on big flake works great for decoding videos to a Surface but they are running in sync mode.

http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt

I have end-to-end decode->YUV420 byte buffer manipulation->encode working with the decoder and encoder operating in async mode and I'm trying to transition to SurfaceTexture manipulation instead but I'm stuck on figuring out how to get the async mode working when it comes to the awaitNewImage() function. You can't stall the decoder/encoder callbacks in async mode. The only thing you can do is feed their inputs with null data.